# Please suggest any scrollbar plugin for angular 6

Tags: angular, scrollbar

I tried 3 plugins for scroll bar [this is the image where I want to insert scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUV8K.png) but not getting the results as required ,I want to use scroll bar for angular 6

Plugins reffered are below:

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUV8K.png)

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-malihu-scrollbar#demo-application][2]

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-smooth-scrollbar][3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For scroll bar we can use this also:

Have a look below :use this in the section in which you need scroll bar

```
<div [style.overflow]="'auto'" [style.height.px]="'250'">
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar) and if you need example how to use it check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mech1e)

Answer (score 0):

Try angular material.

[Angular material scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the Angular Material `scrolling` package?

#### Install Angular CDK

`npm install --save @angular/cdk`

#### Import the scrolling module

`import {ScrollingModule} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';`

#### HTML

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="1" class="viewport">
    <div class="scrolling-example">
        Insert text here...
    </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

#### CSS

```
.viewport {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.scrolling-example {
    height: auto;
}
```

For more details see the [Angular CDK scrolling documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)

For a working example see: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dravlegknmm?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html)